# Error upgrading Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-admin, django-1.6

I am upgrading my Django app to from `1.3 to 1.6` and getting following error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at / 'firstof' is not a valid tag or filter in tag
library 'future'
```

---

```
Error during template rendering In template
/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html,
error at line 1

'firstof' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'future'


{% load admin_static %}{% load firstof from future %}<!DOCTYPE html>
```

---

**Here is the trace back**

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  101.         compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in get_parent
  98.         return get_template(parent)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  127.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  43.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  49.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
  149.     return Template(source, origin, name)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  125.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_string
  153.     return parser.parse()
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  278.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in load
  1074.                                               (name, taglib))

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: 'firstof' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'future'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running Django 1.6?`{% load firstof from future %}` should work in Django 1.6, but will not work in Django 1.3.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?